# To replace the asp.net Wizard control, what would be the best option?

Tags: asp.net, wizard, web-controls, asp.net-webcontrol

I have asp.net wizard control with 3 steps. In each wizard step i have datagrid with huge data populated. Now there is a technical requirement for removing this wizard and using one best workaround. What would be the best way there? If anyone already tried this migration, please help.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it, what benefits do you hope an alternative will give you?

Comment: Process team expects some performance improvement there and (just) thinking (without sure) that some other workarounds would be there with the experienced guys as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need just show one of three grids
then you can use the MultiView control instead of your Wizard control

Comment: Oleg Kalenchuk, thanks for your response. I couldn't convince the process team. Expecting some innovation here with the performance improvement....its interesting...but blank :)